# How can i make a .bat file which runs commands inside adb shell

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, adb, android-uiautomator

I want to create a .bat file in which i can use following command :

```
adb shell
uiautomator runtest StandbyCase.jar -c sprd.powertest.Standby &
```

The second line will not work here. I have tried :

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest StandbyCase.jar -c sprd.powertest.Standby &
```

But in this case & will not work. It is used to keep the process running in backgound. So, i want to run

```
adb shell
```

first, and then

```
uiautomator runtest StandbyCase.jar -c sprd.powertest.Standby &
```

Can anyone suggest how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using;

```
adb shell "runtest StandbyCase.jar -c sprd.powertest.Standby &;uiautomator runtest StandbyCase.jar -c sprd.powertest.Standby &"
```

in a normal batch file.

This can be used for up-to 20 lines.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked.. i used adb shell "uiautomator runtest StandbyCase.jar -c sprd.powertest.Standby &"

Comment: Happy to Help! :)

Comment: Hi, can you help me with one more thing..?? I am trying to run this command : adb shell "uiautomator runtest StandbyCase.jar -c sprd.powertest.Standby &:svc data disable:input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER"   but it does not run other two commands.. can you help, please..

Comment: @HimanshuRautela It's a Semicolon in between not colon. Try with a semicolon.

Comment: with semicolon it is showing : syntax error : ' ; '  not expected

Comment: `&` is the delimiter, don't add any extra `;`